# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2' to data type int

Tags: stored-procedures

When I pass more than one id in sql server stored procedure it throws error like this==> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2' to data type int.
and this is the sql query
===>SELECT * FROM SomeTAble WHERE colName in(@Ids)

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure parameter expecting `varchar(n)`, please have a look at accepted answer from [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string) to split the value from a `varchar`.

Then you can apply the function in your stored procedure, you can simply change the query to something like this:

`alter procedure your_stored_procedure
 @ids varchar(50)
 as
 begin
     select *
     from some_table
     where colName in (splitstring(@ids))
 end
 go`

However, if your stored procedure accepting `int` as parameter, please change it to `varchar` or any data type. Your stored procedure won't work because int will only accept single integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split string  into rows first.

for do that you can use my sql Splitext function

Here is Installing Script

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS [dbo].[SplitText]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SplitText]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
BEGIN
execute dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitText]
( @TextForSplit varchar(1000)
, @SplitWith    varchar(5) = '',''
)       
RETURNS  @DataSource TABLE 
(
    ID  TINYINT identity,
    [Value] VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @XML xml = N''<r><![CDATA['' + REPLACE(@TextForSplit, @SplitWith, '']]></r><r><![CDATA['') + '']]></r>''
        INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Value])
        SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(T.c.value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(128)'')))
        FROM @xml.nodes(''//r'') T(c)

        DELETE @DataSource WHERE [VALUE] = ''''
        RETURN    
END 
END
GO
```

And this is how to use it.

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTAble WHERE colName in( select value from Splittext('1,2,3,4,5' , ','))
```